# Copy a git repository without history

Tags: git, repository

I would like to copy our repository into a new one, keeping our branches in their current state, but delete all useless commit history.

Is there a smart way to do that? Rather than just cloning and copying each branch one after the other?

Comment: What do you mean by 'useless' commit history? Are you referring to all commits before the earliest ancestor of all relevant branches?

Comment: In any Git repository, the commits *are* the history. If you want a new, different history, make new, different commits. If you want *no* history, start with an empty repository. Add new commits, and they become its history. That's all there is to it because that's all there *is.*

Comment: I meant squash history of all relevant branches, so we have a fresh repository but still have all work in progress in branches.
I guess the best solution is to copy the repo and rebase all the branches

Comment: You want to flatten the entire history of each branch? At that point, why not make a new repo, and for each branch, check it out, copy/paste the state of the working tree to the new repo, commit the changes, and name the branch?

Comment: I feel stupid but yeah, that's what I ended up doing. It is, indeed, the easiest solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said here [Copy a git repository without history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50672387/copy-a-git-repository-without-history#comment88362784_50672387) making a new repo and copying each branch is the easiest solution

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you are looking for but i am not sure if this is the exact answer you wanted

Stephenhardy suggested here - https://gist.github.com/stephenhardy/5470814

and his post is

```
-- Remove the history from 
rm -rf .git

-- recreate the repos from the current content only
git init
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"

-- push to the github remote repos ensuring you overwrite history
git remote add origin git@github.com:<YOUR ACCOUNT>/<YOUR REPOS>.git
git push -u --force origin master
```

Comment: The problem with that solution is that I would lose all the branches